# bash - extract day of week of variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

What is the syntax to extract the day of the week from a stored date variable?
The `dateinfile` format is always `[alphanum]_YYYYMMDD`.

In this pseudocode example, trying to get `dayofweek` to store Saturday:

```
#! /bin/bash 

dateinfile="P_20090530"
dayofweek="$dateinfile -u +%A"
```

Answer (score 7):

```
[me@home]$ date --date=${dateinfile#?_} "+%A"
Saturday
```

Or, to put it as you've requested:

```
[me@home]$ dayofweek=$(date --date=${dateinfile#?_} "+%A")
[me@home]$ echo $dayofweek
Saturday
```

Comment: dayofweek=date --date=${dateinfile#?_} "+%A"    but it gives bad substitution error

Comment: @toop what do you get when you `echo $BASH_VERSION` from within your script?

Comment: 4.0.17(1)-release.  New error following your edit: `dayofweek=$' unexpected

Comment: That's odd. It [should work](http://ideone.com/c7BCh). Did you `echo $BASH_VERSION` from within your script or in the command line? Try it from your script.

Answer (score 3):

```
date -d $(echo $dateinfile | cut -f2 -d_) -u +%A
```

The inner expression separates the `20090530` from `P_20090530`, and the outer one extracts the day of week from that date

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same output recently and googled upon this, but I had the same problem stating Bad Substition error.

I then read the date manual and made my version up as follows:

```
#! /bin/sh
dateinfile="P_20090530"
dayofweek=`date --reference $dateinfile +%A`
echo $dayofweek
```